# What's stopping someone from force logging into cookie authentication with 'document.cookie='?

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, backend

Let's say you're using express sessions to provide a session cookie & storage. How would you authenticate that a user is actually that user? Can any random person get an "authenticated" cookie and import it into their browser via the developer console `document.cookie='cookie=IAMACOOKIE'`? At this point they have all access to the account(unless session has expired).

Sorry if this is a dumb question! I'm only recently starting to get into web stuf.

Comment: It's called ["Session hijacking"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)

Comment: If someone has unrestricted access to your machine and can read secrets from it, then there is nothing you can do. Generally speaking the internet provides security between your laptop and the target server - if an attacker controls either end then game over.

Comment: Typically, [one uses `HttpOnly` cookies, which can't be set (or retrieved) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6217795/215552).

Comment: @HereticMonkey True, but you can still set them using Developer Tools. Or you don't even have to use a browser, you can use `curl` or `wget` to send the cookie.

Comment: @HereticMonkey not relevant here. Scenario is attacker has a cookie - code snippet is how they would use it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider "not relevant here" except for the fact that the OP used `document.cookie = ""` as the example. Except for the fact that it's part of the question asked, you are absolutely right that it's not relevant.

Comment: the session ID is held in a cookie, but that should be a) shortlived, and b) not guessable, so an attacker can't simply guess a cookie value and have a realistic change of hijacking a real user's actual session. If the user stays logged in and lets a malicious user poke around inside their browser on their machine, then yes they can discover the cookie and use it, but that's why the session should be short-lived, and also why you shouldn't let untrusted people use your machine without logging out first! (Of course in this situation they can just go to the site and be already logged in as you!)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Follow up question. If a user were to show/send the cookie info to another person; could they import that data onto their own machine/browser, allowing them to "be" that user until the session expires?

Comment: in theory, yes I believe so (although I am no expert, I could be wrong). Why would the user do this though?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I don't necessarily think a user WOULD do this. I'm more-so just trying to learn about all the potential ways one could "pretend" to be a user with a cookie. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @RobinZigmond moreover, so what if the user allows somebody else to log in as them? I mean, they could just give out their username and password as well. That would also allow somebody else to gain access. Or the user can just authenticate on another browser and intentionally leave that for somebody else. Or, heck, they could use the same machine as an "illegitimate" person. The cookie sharing is probably towards the last ways any normal users would try to "cheat" the system.

Comment: @VLAZ Exactly! There are obviously more ways(and easier ways) that a user could go through "cheating" the system. My example was more in the mindset of let's say your authentication is a platform such as Google, Twitter, Discord, or whatever else. If you "pass" the authentication, you're given access via a cookie. Someone else could essentially get this cookie info and pretend to be said Discord(or other auth) user within your application/website for the specified cookie maxAge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session cookies are generally protected in a several ways:

1. They must be cryptographically hard to "guess" or attack with a brute-force attack.  This will typically also include encryption based on a server-side "secret".
2. They should be protected with an `https` transport so that there is no way for any man-in-the-middle to grab the cookie and then use it.  Note a very vulnerable situation is a cookie used of `http` on a public WiFi network.  At that point the owner of the WiFi network or someone who hacked into the WiFi network could easily be collecting cookies.  But, if the cookie is always under `https` and marked as `secure` (such that the browser will never send the cookie over `http`), then it's not subject to the hacked public WiFi.  End-users can also use VPNs to protect themselves on public WiFi, but really any web-site that wants or needs to protect their user's auth credentials must run on `https` such that the credentials are automatically protected, even on public WiFi.
3. Session cookies should be given the options `Secure` and `HttpOnly`.  This prevents them from ever being sent over `http` and prevents client-side Javascript in a web page from accessing them.
4. Session cookies should have a relatively short lifetime (time period on the server where they are valid), limiting the number of them that are still alive and subject to guessing attacks.  One has to find a compromise point between security and user experience as you don't want to be forcing the user to log back in every 5 minutes either.
5. Rate limiting (and perhaps even IP blocking) is deployed to detect and prohibit scripted guessing of cookie values.

The point of these protections are that it would be very difficult for a session cookie to be guessed by an attacker or stolen while in transit.

> Let's say you're using express sessions to provide a session cookie & storage. How would you authenticate that a user is actually that user?

The id in the session cookie is a temporary authentication credential.  It is assumes that if you have that cookie, then you are the same user as the one who originally logged in when the session cookie was created (or were given permission by the original user to use the session).

> If a user were to show/send the cookie info to another person; could they import that data onto their own machine/browser, allowing them to "be" that user until the session expires?

Yes, one could do that if you really wanted to.  Some web-sites may use some sort of "browser fingerprinting" to attempt to detect the case where a cookie is now being used by a different browser.  But, at that point, the original owner could just lend their username and password to someone else too.  It's just a fact that any legit user has the ability to "lend" their login credentials to anyone they want to (whether that is or isn't a wise thing for them to do).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this. So to make sure the session authentication is secure, the cookie would be randomly generated making it super hard to "guess" and ensuring that if someone were to brute force their way into getting the cookie data, the lifetime of said cookie will practically be expired(if not already expired). The cookie is HttpOnly and the protocol is HTTPS. If one wanted the backend to be more secure; Rate Limiting, checking the IP address of the authenticated user vs the cookie caller, as well as checking browser changes would all be additional ways of tracking malicious users.

Comment: @Beganpier - Yes, except for the comment about IP address.  With lots of users being mobile these days, you should not assume that just because an IP address has changed that something malicious is happening.  The user may have just gone from home WiFi to cellular as they got in their car and left the house or walked out of the coffee shop WiFi.  That will cause an IP address change even though nothing nefarious happened.

Comment: ahh mobile users... That completely slipped my mind. I was just about to mark your question! Thank you again :)